# Best way to put two Controls on each other and manage their visibility - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

just for example:

I have two text boxes, both should be in the same location of the form and both are in the same size. 
I need to make visible one of them due to a contrition.

OK, everything it perfect:

```
if (condition)
{
   txtBox1.Visible = false;
   txtBox2.Visible = true;
}
else
{
   txtBox1.Visible = true;
   txtBox2.Visible = false;
}
```

but there is a small problem in `design mode`! I can not handle and select one of text boxes easily in `design mode`, one is send to back and one is send to front and accessing them will cause troubles!

How can I manage such situations with control ordering and design? Is my way putting two control on each other right? is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put one `TextBox` in the location where you want it (let's say `textbox1` will be in the right location) and put the other textbox nearby on the designer. This way you can easily select them at design time.

Then, in your `Form_Load` event, you just put `textBox2` at the same location as `textbox1`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox2.Location = textbox1.Location;
    textbox2.Visible = false;
```

A better question might be, why are you doing this? A textbox is a textbox, and you already have one in the position that you want. A textbox is there to collect user input. Why show and hide another one in the same place? The user won't know the difference, and your program state will presumably not care the name of the control in which the user has entered data...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can select a single control out of these two. First, by hitting the tab key until you land up on the control you want to select. To optimise the selection you need to first select a different control whose tab order is smaller than both of these.

Second, you can select any control and hit F4 to open properties window. On top of properties window there is a dropdown where you get to see the Control name. You can then choose the control of your choice from this properties window and make changes to properties.

Comment: thanks, But am I doing something right putting two control on each other? is this standard? or pro programmers will do another way?

Comment: @Nofuzy - Putting two controls overlaying each other is not the right way of doing it. What you're trying to achieve is dynamically make only one control available. Instead you can create the control of choice at runtime and put it in the place you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can do somethings like this, Here is the sample code,

```
txtBox1.Visible = false;

Point loc = new Point(50, 60); //new location point
txtBox2.Location = loc; //changing location of txtBox2
txtBox2.Visible = true;
```